# Is Ninject creating 2 separate context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I'm creating a Web API and I'm using dependency inject wit Ninject.

I have:

IRTWRepository 
IModelFactory

I'm injecting those 2 into my controllers like this.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IRTWRepository>().To<RTWRepository>();
            kernel.Bind<RTWAPIContext>().To<RTWAPIContext>();          
            kernel.Bind<IModelFactory>().To<ModelFactory>();
        }
```

My RTWRepository constructor looks like this

```
 public class RTWRepository :IRTWRepository
    {
        private RTWAPIContext _context;

        public RTWRepository(RTWAPIContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }}
```

My ModelFactory constructor looks like this

```
public class ModelFactory : IModelFactory
    {
        private IRTWRepository _repo;        

        public ModelFactory(IRTWRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        } 
}
```

I have a Controller that looks like this:

```
public MaterialsController(IRTWRepository repository,IModelFactory modelFactory) 
            : base(repository,modelFactory)
        {

        }
```

Now, my question is : Is Ninject creating 2 separate contexts when creating an instance of my RTWRepository and also when creating an instance of ModelFactory?.

The reason that I'm asking that is because I'm having a problem when I try to save an entity that has a dependency to another object which was previously retrieve from the db.

I'm saving the entity in my controller but I'm creating it in my model factory along with is dependency.

```
public class RecycleCenter
    {
        public RecycleCenter()
        {

        }

        public int MyProperty { get; set; }


        [Required]
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }        
    }
```

The code above is for the entity Recycle Center which has an Address, this recycle center entity is created in my model factory and then in my controller I try to save it but when my repository execute this line

```
 _context.RecycleCenters.Add(entity);
```

I'm getting this error

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker
```

So, somewhere in my code I'm using 2 context instead of 1 and I think is when creating the `ModelFactory` and `RTWRepository`, is this assumption correct?, if so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR;

You probably need to change this line:

```
kernel.Bind<RTWAPIContext>().To<RTWAPIContext>();
```

to

```
kernel.Bind<RTWAPIContext>().To<RTWAPIContext>().InRequestContext();
```

Explanation:

When you define a binding in Ninject, you also specify how that object's lifecycle should be handled.

If you don't explicitly define it, Ninject's default lifecycle is `Transient`. `Transient` means that each time an instance is required, it will create a new one. In your case, you need to two instances: one for the `RTWRepository` of the `ModelFactory` and one for the `RTWRepository` of the `MaterialsController`.

You can modify the lifestyle to one of these options:

- Singleton ==> `kernel.Bind<RTWAPIContext>().To<RTWAPIContext>().InSingleTonScope();`
- Request ==> `kernel.Bind<RTWAPIContext>().To<RTWAPIContext>().InRequestScope();`
- Thread ==> `kernel.Bind<RTWAPIContext>().To<RTWAPIContext>().InThreadScope();`
- Named, Call, Parent, Custom

In your case, I think you need `InRequestScope`, but you have to check the necessary lifecycle as it depends on the application.

For further information please check out the documentation here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, it is. There's no annotation that is telling to Ninject "Hey, stop, when you have created the instance once, reuse it". You should agree that in most cases, you would want multiple instances of an object and that it is a rare case, where you want it only once.

If you want to reuse the instance, use the singleton pattern. Ninject is familiar with it, so you can bind the object mapping to a method

```
kernel.Bind<RTWAPIContext>().ToMethod(c => RTWAPIContext.GetInstance());
```

There is also a `ToSingleton` binding, but I bet you cannot make your context constructor private and implement C# specific singleton due to other ASP.NET problems (e.g. ASP.NET Identity will try to invoke the context's method for object creation).

Comment: The `ToSingleton`-method has nothing to do with the implementation of the class. You can define a regular class, Ninject will just create one instance and then reuse it. There's no need for a private constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I did not know that. Actually my remark was about the `Create()` method which ASP.NET Identity makes by default in `ApplicationDbContext`. So my thoughts was if one really wants only one instance, to change this method to be a singleton one - used by Ninject, by the developer and by Identity